# What causes an unstable ethernet connectivity with Manta M8P/CB1?

Tags: bigtreetech

I'm working with a Manta M8P and CB1 and the environment I'm working in requires it to be directly connected to the PC via an ethernet cable. (Wi-Fi or ethernet connection to the router is not possible)

However, when I do this, the Mainsail interface is often not viewable and the SSH connection keeps breaking. I remember trying this with a Raspberry Pi in the past and there were no issues seeing Mainsail and SSH work.

Has anyone experienced this or does anyone know what's different with BTT that would cause this? I noticed the device seems to be working when it has an IPV4 address. But it only holds it for a few minutes, and I can tell it loses it when everything starts breaking.